# creating dictionary containing list values using a comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

In python I wish to create a dictionary using a comprehension with keys that are strings, and values that are lists. What I cannot figure out, is how to append elements to these lists. For example consider my following attempt:

```
{c: [].append(x[0]) for x in g16.nodes(data=True) for c in colors if x[1]['color'] == c}
```

g16.nodes(data=True) gives a list of pairs where the first element is a string, and the second element is a dictionary which just specifies a color. As stated, I wish to make this structure into a dictionary, where the keys give the color, and the values are lists of strings which have this color.

If you have the solution, or if there is a better way to do this, please let me know!

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: `list.append` returns None, so all dictionary values are going to be None.

Comment: Use a loop, not a comprehension. You risk writing an incomprehensible comprehension!

Comment: Rule of thumb, if you have to mutate in the comprehension, then comprehension is not the solution.

Comment: I believe `if x[1]['color'] in colors` should be enough, and `colors` can be a set which can offer faster lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to do this:

```
{c: [x[0] for x in g16.nodes(data=True) if x[1]['color'] == c] for c in colors}
```

But it's not very efficient as you are looping over `g16.nodes(data=True)` once for each color

Something like this is better

```
d = {c: [] for c in colors}
for x in g16.nodes(data=True):
    k = x[1]['color']
    if k in d:
        d[k].append(x[0])
```

If you know `k` is always in `colors`, you could simplify to

```
d = {c: [] for c in colors}
for x in g16.nodes(data=True):
    d[x[1]['color']].append(x[0])
```

Comment: I was just typing about this same answer!

Comment: You could also use a `collections.defaultdict(list)` for `d`. It is a classic usage.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE, the main difference between the two alternatives is that this one puts all the colors in as keys. Can make a difference later when you are iterating over it - sometimes you want keys with empty lists, sometimes you don't

Answer (score 0):

Using a comprehension for a dictionary of key to lists is not going to be pretty. It's probably easier if you can try this:

Assuming `g16.nodes(data=True)` is something like

```
[('key1', {'color': 'black'}), ('key2', {'color': 'green')]
```

and the `color` key exists, you can try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
gen = ((k, c['color']) for k, c in g16.nodes(data=True) if c['color'] in colors)
results = defaultdict(list)
for key, color in gen:
    results[color].append(key)
```